# ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/.. 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib

Tags: mysql, anaconda

I use Jupyter notebook to connect the server, and try to 'import mySQLdb', I met some problem:
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

I used 'pip install mysql' for create the mysql environment. When I try to 'pip uninstall mysql' and use 'conda install mysql-python'
it says:

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package certifi conflicts for:
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip
Package setuptools conflicts for:
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates

Comment: Sounds borked. Easiest solution is a reinstall. Please take time to read the best practices for "[*Using Pip in a Conda Env*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)" to avoid such problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve the problem by myself! lol
I just write the missing lib into the mysql
1: disable the csrutil 
2: add lib:
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib